# Vim commands running in bash after I run a python file

Tags: python, bash, vim, rhel, rhel7

I am having an issue after I run a python unit test file.  Once the file exits I can only interact with my console after pressing "i" and using other vim keybindings.  I also noticed that using the arrow keys to traverse what I typed will delete a random number of characters at the end of the line.

EX:

```
$ ./tests.py -v
<output>
$ <cannot type>
<press "i">
$ I can now type
<press <- >
$ I can no
```

I am using RHEL 7 and bash.  I've tried googling this issue but I'm either formatting the question poorly or it is an uncommon issue.

Thank you for the help.

**EDIT:**

The actual test.py contains private code, but this is example contains the same essential code.

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest

class TestUtil(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_hello_world(self):
        text = "Hello World!"
        self.assertEqual("Hello World!", text)
        print(text)
        pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: what does tests.py look like

Comment: Added above, I can't really show the real test.py but essentially I'll create variables, run commands that interface with ansible, print output and pass.

Comment: @DanLowe That was my issue!  If you would put your comment in an answer I'll mark it as correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if your shell is being placed into [vi-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-vi-Mode.html). This is a [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) mode where you can use vi editing keys instead of the more commonly used emacs keys.

There are two ways I know of that this can happen.

```
set -o vi

bindkey -v
```

Technically, to turn it off you use `set +o vi`. However, that will disable all inline editing. It is more likely that you wish to go back to emacs mode, which is usually the default. To do that, do this instead:

```
set -o emacs
```